# IIS 6 and 7 hangs with many web services

Tags: iis, .net, web-services

I have an application that uses one web service asmx file per screen (like 50 screens), I didn't think this was a problem until we did tests.

I tried with IIS7 on windows 2008, it hanged. Since its new to me I changed it to IIS6 on windows 2003, the same thing happened

IIS 6 creates tons of w3mp.exe processes, each 55 MB, and reaches a point where the application is usless.

It has been used only by 10 people at the same time...

any thoughts?

Comment: Are there errors in the Application or System Event Logs?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "screen"?

Comment: By screen I mean a use case or class or module. The errors are on the system event logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found out what the problem was.

First there is no diference between having multiple asmx files  and 1 asmx file.

second, the server hang because I'm using informix, and programmed the application with the informix client sdk 3.5, which hanged randomly opening connections. So I changed all the code to ODBC and it worked like a charm.

third, we had 150 working processes on the connection pool, this created am w3mp.exe process per connection, it should have just 1 worker process.

so, everything works ok now, hope this helps someone out there.